# Python multiple conditions with numpy.where

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do some simple manipulation of a pandas dataframe. I have imported pandas as pd and numpy as np and imported a csv to create a dataframe called 'dfe'.

I have had success with the following code to populate a new column based on one condition:

```
dfe['period'] = np.where(dfe['Time'] >= "07:30:00.000" , '1', '2')
```

But when I try to use a similar technique to populate the same column based on two conditions, I get an error (unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str')

Here is my attempt at the multiple condition version:

```
dfe['period'] = np.where(dfe['Time'] >= "07:30:00.000" & dfe['Time'] <= "10:00:00.000" , '1', '2')
```

I have had a look at lots of solutions to similar problems but they are all a little bit too complicated for me to understand given I have just started and was hoping someone could give me some clues about why this is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are close, `()` are missing because priority of operators:

```
dfe['period'] = np.where((dfe['Time'] >= "07:30:00.000") & 
                         (dfe['Time'] <= "10:00:00.000") , '1', '2')
```

Another solution with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
dfe['period'] = np.where(dfe['Time'].between("07:30:00.000", "10:00:00.000") , '1', '2')
```

Comment: Thank you. The between version is really neat